# Unable to deploy project using dedicated window azure caching (preview) in production environment

Tags: caching, azure, azure-caching

I made a sample application using windows azure dedicated caching ([preview](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/cache/)).

The sample application runs perfectly in emulated environment but does not get properly deployed in production environment: The project and the cache instances always shows that "waiting for role to startup". I am not able to understand whether it is a configuration issue or something else.

Comment: Have you enabled RDP access to your Virtual Machine and checked the Application event log? I am sure you will see some exception to root cause that issue..

Comment: It is very much possible that you may have missed to set Caching Related references to copy local as true because that is #1 mistake made with new applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which deployment mode are you using? Colocated or Dedicated?
If it is colocated can you tell me what value of Cache Size (%) have you set? And which vm type are you deploying?

Also, please check whether you have provided storage account connection string in "Caching Tab" under "storage account credentials to use for maintaining the cache cluster's runtime state" section.

Comment: I have used dedicated caching. My web role has 2 instance running on medium VM and i have 1 cache worker role. Where should I provide storage account connection string (in web role or cache worker role) ? And How do I get storage account connection string ?

Comment: I have tried by giving azure storage account account-name and access key (primary access key) but after starting deployment its still giving status as "Waiting for role to start... System startup tasks are running."

Comment: Thanks it is working. When diagnostic mode is enabled it takes more time to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

In the Cache Worker Role (the role where you have caching service enabled) if you go to "Caching Tab" you will see "storage account credentials to use for maintaining the cache cluster's runtime state" section.

For Emulated environment this value is "UseDevelopmentStorage=true", for deploying to cloud you need to replace this setting with a valid cloud storage account. Please follow detailed instructions for proper configuration at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj131263.aspx

Further if you are still facing the issues, enabling remote desktop and checking "Windows->Application" and/or "Microsoft->Windows-Application Server-System Services/Admin" channel would also help.